# how to stop the table view from repeating an array several times when character range is increased in text field in ios objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

My issue is that I am using google location search api to search locations through text field and want to display the locations in the table view which i have searched, here my search array is repeated according to character range

```
-(void)getLocationsService{

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
    manager.securityPolicy.validatesDomainName = NO;

        [manager POST:[@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=AIzaSyAcO7glhPdyoE7VEt8Ie0jMFnS4Ig3i2os&input=" stringByAppendingString:self.searchTf.text] parameters:@"" progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject)
    {

        NSLog(@"Location Data is:%@",responseObject);

        NSArray *arr=[[NSArray alloc]init];
        arr= [responseObject valueForKey:@"predictions"];

            if (arr.count !=0) {

                for (NSMutableDictionary *dict in arr) {

                    [serverData addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"description"]]];

                    NSLog(@"Location is %@",serverData);

                    }
                [self.tableVw reloadData];
    }

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

        NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }];

}

-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

    [self getLocationsService];
    return YES;
}
```

how to stop the search array from repeating so many times
[image: for example here you can see that "Hyderabad, Telangana, India" is repeated for 3 times]

for example here you can see that "Hyderabad, Telangana, India" is repeated for 3 times

Comment: how to stop the search array from repeating so many times - not clear

Comment: i have added an image for example please check that

Comment: `[serverData addObject:`. You may want to do `[serverData removeAllObjects]` at some point.

Comment: [serverData removeAllObjects]; add this before inserting data into array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like

```
  [serverData removeAllObjects]; // it omit the previous value of array
for (NSMutableDictionary *dict in arr) {

            [serverData addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"description"]]];

            NSLog(@"Location is %@",serverData);

            }
```